# .Net Core Updating to 3.1.31 from 3.1.5 - Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I inherited a project that uses .Net Core and don't really know too much about how to set it up and configure it in IIS.

Prior to updating everything was working and loading fine.

Now I am getting "Internal Server Error: An error occurred while starting the application".

Initially to update I downloaded and installed (in this order):

1. aspnetcore-runtime-3.1.31-win-x64
2. dotnet-runtime-3.1.31-win-x64

On installing the ASP Net Core runtime (1) the site broke, then I installed the dotnet-runtime (2) and the site came back up and everything was loading and running as expected.

Then a colleague noticed that there was a .Net Core 3.1.5 Windows Server Hosting installed and not sure what it was we uninstalled it to see if it broke anything and yes, uninstalling that broke the sites.

So I then downloaded and installed the Hosting Bundle for .Net Core 3.1.31, rebooted, and it still won't load/startup.

From there I uninstalled everything, and re-installed the 3.1.5 version (what was previously installed) and it's still broken.

As best as I can tell, uninstalling the Hosting Bundle (Windows Server Hosting) broke something and I cannot figure out what it is or how to fix it. Possibly something that handles the IIS Support?

I'm hoping someone else has had a similar issue or can maybe direct me to what I should be looking at or for. This doesn't really make sense that a minor version update would cause all these problems and I'm not sure what uninstalling that app changed that didn't get repaired or replaced when installing it again.

Comment: Can you try running the application yourself without IIS? Go to root dir of your application > open powershell/cmd > run dotnet run <your_application.ext> or just start the <your_application.ext> from the powershell/cmd. See what is the output

Answer (score 0):

I found that there are multiple app settings files one for each environment and this is controlled by an environment variable (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

It would appear that uninstalling the Hosting Bundle (Windows Server Hosting) caused this environment variable to be erased and the environment defaults to Production when there is not one set.

So in our case it was using the production config in a staging environment.

We started investigating this once we were able to find a SQL connection error in the server logs which tipped us off to check a few things and this was one of them.

Hopefully someone finds this helpful and it can save someone else some time and frustration.